# Unable to find column names in a FK constraint

Tags: data-warehouse, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I have created two tables in Snowflake.

```
create or replace TRANSIENT TABLE TESTPARENT (
COL1 NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
COL2 VARCHAR(16777216) NOT NULL,
COL3 VARCHAR(16777216) NOT NULL,
constraint UNIQ_COL3 unique (COL3)
);


create or replace TRANSIENT TABLE TESTCHILD3 (
COL_A NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
COL_B NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL,
ABCDEF VARCHAR(16777216) NOT NULL,
constraint FKEY_1 foreign key (COL_A, COL_B) references TEST_DB.PUBLIC.TESTPARENT1(COL1,COL2),
constraint FKEY_2 foreign key (ABCDEF) references TEST_DB.PUBLIC.TESTPARENT(COL3)
);
```

Now I want to execute a query and see the names of columns that are involved in `FKEY_2 FOREIGN KEY`
in Table `TESTCHILD3`, but it seems like there are no DB Table/View that keeps this information. I can find out the column names for `UNIQUE KEY & PRIMARY KEY` but there is nothing for `FOREIGN KEYS`.

**EDIT**
I have already tried `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS`, along with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` and all the other system tables. No luck. Only `DESC TABLE` is giving me some info related to `CONSTRAINTS` and `COLUMNS` but that also has `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINTS` information missing.

Answer (score 2):

SHOW IMPORTED KEYS IN TABLE <fk_table_name>;

Comment: This worked for me. It also accepts `IN SCHEMA` and `IN DATABASE` variants.

Comment: where did you find this command? It appears to be undocumented!

Answer (score 1):

Updated answer:

I was checking on something unrelated and noticed a very efficient way to list all primary and foreign keys:

```
show exported keys in account; -- Foreign keys
show primary keys in account;
```

When you limit the call to a table, it appears you have to request the foreign keys that point to the parent table:

```
show exported keys in table "DB_NAME"."SCHEMA_NAME"."PARENT_TABLE";
```

You can check the documentation for how to limit the show command to a specific database or schema, but this returns rich information in a table very quickly.

Comment: Thanks, yeah if you execute `SELECT GET_DDL('Table', 'table_name')` then it would give the DDL that will contain the FK and everything else. It would work. 
But my necessity is different, I am adding support for Snowflake Data Warehouse in a data modeler, where I need to reverse engineer everything in a data model. I can go ahead and use the DDL parse it and create the model but the DDL can change over time with new releases and parser may stop working after some time.

Comment: Gotcha. I actually wrote something that will walk through every table and report the FKs, but due to complexity I wrote it in Java. I may revisit writing it in an SP at some point. One of my customers took the code I wrote in the JAR and did some slight modifications to use with their modeling tools. If it's any use to you, you can find the JAR file and Java source here: https://snowflake.pavlik.us/index.php/2020/01/12/snowflake-relationships-java-utilities/

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to query this view: INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS

Note: TABLE_CONSTRAINTS only displays objects for which the current role for the session has been granted access privileges.

For more see: https://docs.snowflake.net/manuals/sql-reference/info-schema/table_constraints.html

Comment: Thanks, but I already tried that, along with `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS` and all the other system tables. No luck. Only `DESC TABLE` is giving me some info related to constraints and columns but that also has FK Constraints' information missing.